# Keep Unhandled layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers

I saved a .qgs file with home server postgis layers. Had to work remotely, but will lose unhandled layers upon opening the file. I can connect to these through my GeoServer, but I'm going to lose my styles and queries and have to literally rebuild my map from scratch. Is there a way to keep QGIS from dropping these unhandled layers so I can refer to them when rebuilding the map remotely?

Answer (score 1):

You could set the .qgs file `read-only` within the file system to prevent dropping the layers.

Or work on a copy of it when working remotely.